# Название шва в рукоделии - "вперёд иголку", "вперёд иголкой" или "вперёд иголка"? В кавычках?

Tags: термины

Название шва в рукоделии - "вперёд иголку", "вперёд иголкой" или "вперёд иголка"? В кавычках?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книгах с самыми умными названиями конкурируют только два варианта из трёх: *(техника) "вперёд иголк**у**"* (Орнамент русской народной вышивки как историко-этнографический источник) и  (*шов*) "вперёд иголк**ой**" (Вопросы лексикологии, лексикографии и прикладной лингвистики, Институт языкознания АН СССР). Хотя во многих других изданиях и то, и другое приписывают "шву", ключевым моментом для выбора мне представляется употребление с тем или иным видовым наименованием - важно, "*шов*" это или "*техника*". "**Шов**" *статически* описывает результат: как выполнен этот элемент вышивки, каким швом? Это шито вперёд иголк**ой** (ср. белыми нитками)! Если же речь идёт о **технике** (о методе - какие движения при этом совершаются), то можно говорить о *динамике*: при этом шве *двигают вперёд* иголк**у**. В этом смысле, несмотря на разнобой в массовом употреблении, мне видится *более точным* выражение "**шов вперёд иголкой**" (как и *техника "вперёд иголку"*). Императив же "вперёд(,) иголка" на этом фоне выглядит просторечием, навеянным старосоветскими лозунгами вроде "время, вперёд!".